# Sum of integer squares with zero sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is something that I perhaps should know but don't. What is known about sums $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=0$ where $a_i$ are integer? Specifically, which even integers can be represented by such sums when $k=4$? Or when $k=5$?

Comment: for k=4: 1,-2,-3,4

Comment: Are the $a_I$ required to be distinct? Also can any be $0$?

Comment: Can be zero, can be equal to each other. Of course, only nonnegative even integers can be represented.

Comment: It's a good question, and can say for example that if $n=a^2+b^2$ then $2n=(a)^2+(-a)^2+(b)^2+(-b)^2$ so that $2n$ is represented. This leaves a lot of gaps, and some of those can be filled in using more than two different abs vals among the $a_i$

Comment: For $k=3$ an integer $n$ can be represented iff $n/2$ is of the form $a^2+b^2+ab$ (the number of representations are also equal). The representation of integers of the form $a^2+b^2+ab$ are well studied

Comment: For $k=4$, in some way the number of representation of $n$ for $k=4$ is equal to the number of representation of $8n$ as $4x^2+7y^2+21z^2 $ and for the solutions you can use representation of integers as trinary quadratic forms. Observe also that for $k=4$ you will obtain a quadratic form with four variables and they are also studied and some great results are done by Ramanujan. Hence the general idea is to replace $a_k$ with $-\sum a_1+a_2+....a_{k-1}$ and write the resultant quadratic form in a canonical way.

Comment: For $k=5$ all even integers are representable

Comment: @Elaqqad I know the $k=3$ statement. For $k=5$ that was my guess as well, but I was curious if there were references. I would imagine that someone must have calculated the corresponding theta functions. While the sum of squares story is well-known, this, arguably more symmetric, situation did not attract as much attention.